# multiple matches per line or multiline mutiple matches with regex

Tags: python, regex

### First: simplified question.

In the following text:

```py
text = b'List ---\r\n\r\nDATA 0:\r\n     SN: 1234656AZDSQVC\r\n     FW: DSQ\r\n\r\nDATA 1:\r\n     SN: 1234ZDS656AQVC\r\n     FW: 656A\r\n\r\n----------------------------------\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

I'm looking to find two matches, "0" then "1".

I tried with the following regex

```
arrayResult = re.findall(".*(?:DATA.*([\d])+.*SN:).*",text)
```

but I only get the last match : "1" and not the first "0". If I add more data, I always get the last one...

```
arrayResult: ['1']
```

### Here comes the full question:

In the same text, i'm in fact looking for a mutiple tuple match:

- ("0","1234656AZDSQVC","DSQ")
- ("1","1234ZDS656AQVC","656A")
- ...
- ("9","1234ZDS6SXAXXC","6BBA")

I tried with the following regex without success (I only get the last tuple):

```
arrayResult = re.findall(r".*(?:DATA.*([\d])+.*SN:[\s]+([\d\w]+).*FW:[\s]+([\d\w]+)).*",text)
```

---

**what is the correct way to find these tuples?**

Comment: Are you sure you are running a string regex on a byte string?

Comment: At any rate, the main problem is that `.*` at the start goes to the end of the string, and the rest of the subpatterns only match the last occurrence. You must remove the `.*` at both ends for sure

Comment: Try `matches = re.findall(r'DATA\s+(\d+):\s+SN:\s+(\w+)\s+FW:\s+(\w+)', text)` if your text is actually a string. See [demo](https://ideone.com/8pMJjk) and [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oDA5uB/1). I would not rely on `.*?` with `re.DOTALL`, it might be fraught with issues in case you can have more entries with missing `SN` or `FW` nodes.

Comment: this question might not deserve upvotes as easy as it is to see the obvious I didn't see. However it does not deserve downvotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
text = b'List ---\r\n\r\nDATA 0:\r\n     SN: 1234656AZDSQVC\r\n     FW: DSQ\r\n\r\nDATA 1:\r\n     SN: 1234ZDS656AQVC\r\n     FW: 656A\r\n\r\n----------------------------------\r\n\r\n\r\n'
matches = re.findall(r'\b(\d+):.*?\bSN: ([\dA-Z]+).*?FW: ([\dA-Z]+)', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('1234656AZDSQVC', 'DSQ'), ('1234ZDS656AQVC', '656A')]
```

The regex pattern I use simply targets a leading `0:` or `1:` section prefix, and then uses two capture groups for the `SN:` and `FW:` contents.

Not sure about your `text` string.  If the above doesn't work for you, then don't make the text a byte string.

Comment: [It throws an exception](https://ideone.com/q3cMhQ), thus it does not print any results.

Comment: [Not on Python 2.x](https://rextester.com/ERDC3394) ... what are you running in your demo?

Comment: In Python 2.x, all strings are byte strings, there would be no need of `b` prefix, thus, I believe OP is using Python 3.x

Comment: indeed python 3.8

Comment: @GuillaumeD My answer should work on 3.x as well, so long as `text` is not a byte string.  Kill the `b` prefix in that case.

Comment: it works with some few modifications, the key is the use of \b I reckon, could you explain what was wrong in my regex?

Comment: I didn't read through your regex, since you said it wasn't working and it looked overly complex.  Actually, I think the critical thing here is to use lazy dot `.*?` in the pattern to make sure we don't jump across sections unexpectedly.

Comment: by the way, i'm still getting the "\r\n\r\n" after the matches

Comment: @GuillaumeD It is not the word boundary that is important. You are overusing `.` in your pattern, with greedy quantifiers.